# Peer to Peer видео чат. С чего начать?

Tags: c#, .net, p2p

Здравствуйте.

Написал видеочат на основе "клиент-сервер". Сейчас хочу сделать то же самое на оснрове peer to peer. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, с чего начать. Перерыл, как мне кажется, все, что можно, на русском и на английском. Почитал, что это и как работает (теорию). Хотелось бы больше практических примеров. Может, кто-нибудь видел ссылки на что-то подобное. Интересуют любая реализация peer to peer, будь то чат или ещё что-то, не важно. Хотелось бы на рабочее решение посмотреть. Взглянуть "изнутри, так сказать. Поделитесь, пожалуйста. :)

Comment: А ничем по идее не отличается. Первый клиент становится сервером, вот и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать WCF, у него есть режим работы p2p, и гонять данные видео потока между клиентами, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx
Насчет задержки только не знаю.